# PHP Laravel with Blade Output. Create html instead of string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to have a string as html with blade. I am not sure how to do this with blade using laravel. I have the following code:

```
<option value="New York" "{{{ Input::old('state', $user->state == 'New York' ?  'selected' : '') }}}">
```

The output of this is

```
 <option value="New York" "selected">New York</option>
```

and I want it to be this

```
<option value="New York" selected>New York</option>
```

How can I do this? Pointing me to resources would also help. Thank you.

Comment: what happens when you remove the quotes around the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<option value="New York" {{{ Input::old('state', $user->state) == 'New York' ?  'selected' : '' }}}>
```

Simply remove the quotes. Also it looks like you have a parenthesis in the wrong place. I fixed that as well.

And just an FYI for you, you can use Laravel's Form class to generate a `select` for you and automatically select the right option for you:

```
{{{ Form::select('state', $statesArray, Input::old('state', $user->state)) }}}
```

Comment: When I remove the quotes I get an error "Use of undefined constant selected - assumed 'selected' " . I will try the form generator and if that works I will accept your answer.

Comment: you are removing the wrong quote. look at the answer carefully.

Comment: @itachi is correct. Make sure you don't remove the quotes around `'selected'` as it is a string. Rather, remove the quotes around the blade `{{{ }}}` syntax which results in `selected` being unquoted in the HTML, which is what you desire.